# Excel functions with dynamic range

Tags: excel, csv, export-to-excel, export-to-csv

So I am creating a .csv file with data I want to plot in excel, however I want to plot the sum of them.
e.g.

set 1:

```
0 5 6 67
5 6 1 0
```

set2:

```
8 5 4 664
1 2 5 694
6 4 1 545
```

So I want the sum of each column in set1 as a row in the end and the sum of each column in set2 at the end. But the problem is that set1 and set2 might have a different number of rows.

Is there any easy FORMULA that I can export with the .csv to do so in excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand your question correctly, but you might try this:

Assuming that the top left number is in Cell A1, you could use the following formula:

```
=SUM(OFFSET($A$1, 0, COLUMN()-1, ROW()-1, 1))
```

Print this into every cell of the last row of your sheet. This way, you have a fixed formula for every cell that works regardless of the number of columns or rows, even when the rows have different lengths.

Example for set2:

```
8   5   4   664
1   2   5   694
6   4   1   545
15  11  10  1903    <-- formula pasted here
```